# Modifying one element in a four dimensional orthogonal matrix and recalculating to make it orthogonal again.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a four dimensional orthogonal matrix, and modifying the value in just one of its elements, how can the remaining elements in the matrix be recalculated to become orthogonal again? Because there are six degrees of freedom, is there more than one possible solution to a given problem (as defined above)?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to apply Gram-Schmidt to the columns or rows, using the modified one as the starting point. The resulting matrix will certainly depend on the order in which you feed it into the algorithm. There are also some algorithms in the realm of image processing that compute the “nearest” orthogonal matrix to a given one.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "recalculating" here. What relation do you expect between the new matrix and the old? Given your new entry, one can complete the matrix to be orthogonal in infinitely many ways; are all acceptable?

Comment: Yes, any solution that keeps the new entry intact is fine. The preferable solution if there are an infinite number of them is any solution that has the least euclidean distance from the original matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the new entry intact? Must it remain fixed at the value to which it’s been set? If so, are you guaranteed that its absolute value is no greater than one?

Comment: Yes, it must remain fixed. Its absolute value is guaranteed to be <= 1